# Drupal 6 clean urls without domain name (accessing via IP Address)

Tags: uri

Is there a way to do clean urls without a domain name; just using an IP Address. The option is disabled when using ip address.

Comment: I test and use D6 here on my Macbook with MAMP and have clean urls with 192.168.1.XXX:8888 all the time.  Where is it disabled for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clean URLs is not dependent on domain names it is disabled because your server doesnt support it. You need to enable `mod_rewrite` module in apache to get that option enabled.
Check out the [server configuration section here](http://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls).

Comment: It was an error in the .htaccess file

Comment: @Chris Muench: what was wrong with .htaccess file?